# Opening an External URL Page in my Modal Dialog and capture some of the information that's being submitted to the parent React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a Component called Dashboard which is opening a modal dialog, what I want is, I want to open an external url like google.com in that modal dialog, what user enters in the search textbox I want to capture it into my parent Window or component, is that possible, if it is not from google.com, then some other url, is it possible using React JS/React native?
Here is Dashboard component code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Modal } from './Modal';

class Dashboard extends React.Component {
    state = { show: false };

showModal = () => {
    this.setState({ show: true });
};

hideModal = () => {
    this.setState({ show: false });
};

render() {
    return (
        <main>
            <h1>React Modal</h1>
            <Modal show={this.state.show} handleClose={this.hideModal}>
                <p>Modal</p>
                <p>Data</p>
            </Modal>
            <button type="button" onClick={this.showModal}>
                open
    </button>
        </main>
    );
}
}    
export default Dashboard;
```

Here is my Modal js code

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import './ModalSS.css';

export const Modal = ({ handleClose, show, children }) => {
    const showHideClassName = show ? "modal display-block" : "modal display-none";
return (
    <div className={showHideClassName}>
        <section className="modal-main">
            {children}
            <button onClick={handleClose}>close</button>
        </section>
    </div>
 );
}
```

Here is my CSS:

```
 body {
}

.modal {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

.modal-main {
    position: fixed;
    background: white;
    width: 80%;
    height: 80%;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}

.display-block {
    display: block;
}

.display-none {
    display: none;
}
```

Any idea how can I load a new external url in this modal and when user enters values and clicks on search or submit, it closes the modal and sends some of the information to the end parent component. Is it possible, if yes how can I do it - any help please - thanks in advance.

Comment: When you say external site, is it one that is cooperating with you in this development effort?

Comment: No but something like Survey Monkey, user enters information but there is some information like First name, last name and comments we want to capture from that website which is displayed within our modal dialog, url is like this: https://www.surveymonkey.com/dashboard/

Comment: Hmm, being able to capture user data from an embedded 3rd party website is an attack vector. You're going to have a lot of trouble doing this, and that's a good thing. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options